# zabbix agent vs agent2

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am working on deploying Zabbix in our organization and comparing zabbix agent vs agent2

I found following link which is useful,

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation...ent_comparison

I just have a couple of questions:

- For agent2 "Daemonization" is "no". Does it mean agent2 service does not run in background? That does not seem right...
- Similarly "Drop user privileges" is "no". To me it sounds like the service would run as "root". However on testing, I can see that service is running as "zabbix" user.

Also, is there anything else I should know when using agent2? e.g. any limitations, gotchas?

Thank you
J

Answer (score 3):

I posted the same question on zabbix forum and got this reply.

> zabbix agent 2 is capable of doing all agent 1 does + some more. It's not "daemonized" on *NIX because this job is propagated to systemd. The same with privileges, while agent 1 is capable of switching user that it is run as, agent 2 doesn't have this functionality and this is controlled by systemd instead.

> Fixed documentation, let me know if it's more clear now.

Source: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/422788-zabbix-agent-vs-agent2

Comment: Is a good idea to post the link of the source you're relying on- in this case the discussion forum thread.